# GUI application printing out wrong result

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

Ok so i have a Java Program that looks into the sales report of how many tickets and refreshments sold. I have completed the program. It has two files a TheaterSales.java file and a GUI Driver Class. 
In this program the user enters a number of each item sold and the program then determines what the sales is for each item and the total sales of all the items. The way it determines this is by the user entering the number of each item sold and pressing on the "Calculate Sales Total" button. 
When i entered the number of each sold items the sales and total cost all come out to be zero.
What could be a possible error that i am not seeing or code that could be missing.

```
//Worker Class
public class TheaterSales_1 {
//Create instance variable for adult tickets, child tickets, popcorn and drinks
private double adultTickets;
private double childTickets;
private double popcorn;
private double drinks;
//Getters and setters for each instance variable    
public double getAdultTickets() {
    return adultTickets;
}
public void setAdultTickets(double adultTickets) {
    this.adultTickets = adultTickets;
}
public double getChildTickets() {
    return childTickets;
}
public void setChildTickets(double childTickets) {
    this.childTickets = childTickets;
}
public double getPopcorn() {
    return popcorn;
}
public void setPopcorn(double popcorn) {
    this.popcorn = popcorn;
}
public double getDrinks() {
    return drinks;
}
public void setDrinks(double drinks) {
    this.drinks = drinks;
}
//Constants for the cost of the tickets and refreshments
final double adult = 9.50;
final double child = 5.75;
final double food = 5.50;
final double beverage = 3.25;
//Two constructors, one must be a default constructor
public TheaterSales_1(){    
    adultTickets = 0;
    childTickets = 0;
    popcorn = 0;
    drinks = 0; 
}
public TheaterSales_1(double adultTickets, double childTickets,
                      double popcorn, double drinks ){  
setAdultTickets(adultTickets);
setChildTickets(childTickets);
setPopcorn(popcorn);
setDrinks(drinks);  
}
//Methods to calculate and return sales for adult tickets, child tickets, popcorn,                                               
    drinks and the total sales
public double getAdultTicketSales()
{
return adultTickets*adult;
}
public double getChildTicketSales()
{
return childTickets*child;
}
public double getPopcornSales()
{
return popcorn*food;
}
public double getDrinkSales()
{
return drinks*beverage;
}
public double getTotalSales()
{
return getAdultTicketSales() + getChildTicketSales() + getPopcornSales()+   
    getDrinkSales();
}

public String toString(){

    String str = "ACME Theater\n\n"; //Title of the Panel

    str += "Adult Tickets " + String.format("$%,.2f", adult);

    str += "Child Tickets " + String.format("$%,.2f", child);

    str += "Popcorn " + String.format("$%,.2f", popcorn);

    str += "Drinks " + String.format("$%,.2f", drinks);

    str += "Total Sales " + String.format("$%,.2f", getTotalSales());       
    return str;

}
```

}

```
//GUI Driver Class

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class G_Driver extends JFrame {
private JPanel northPanel;
private JPanel southPanel;
private JPanel eastPanel;
private JPanel westPanel;

private JLabel nLabel;
private JLabel sLabel;
private JLabel totSales;

private JLabel adTickets;
private JLabel chTickets;
private JLabel popCorn;
private JLabel drinkS;

private JTextField adTicketsTxt;
private JTextField chTicketsTxt;
private JTextField popcornTxt;
private JTextField drinksTxt;
private JTextField TotalSalesTxt;

private JButton calcSalesButton;
private JButton closeButton;

private TheaterSales_1 TS;

final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;
final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

/**
 * 
 * Constructor
 */
public G_Driver(){
    setTitle("ACME Theater Sales Report");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Calling the methods for the three regions of the window
    topPanel();
    centerPanel();
    bottomPanel();

    setVisible(true);
}

//Writing the top Panel private method
private void topPanel(){
    northPanel = new JPanel();
    nLabel = new JLabel("ACME Theater");
    northPanel.add(nLabel);
    add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

//Writing the center Panel private method
private void centerPanel(){
    eastPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4));

    JPanel quantity = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));
    adTickets = new JLabel("Adult Tickets");
    adTicketsTxt = new JTextField(3);

    chTickets = new JLabel("Child Tickets");
    chTicketsTxt = new JTextField(3);

    popCorn = new JLabel("Popcorn");
    popcornTxt = new JTextField(3);

    drinkS = new JLabel("Drinks");
    drinksTxt = new JTextField(3);

    quantity.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Quantity"));
    quantity.add(adTickets);
    quantity.add(adTicketsTxt);
    quantity.add(chTickets);
    quantity.add(chTicketsTxt);
    quantity.add(popCorn);
    quantity.add(popcornTxt);
    quantity.add(drinkS);
    quantity.add(drinksTxt);

    eastPanel.add(quantity);

    JPanel sales = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));
    adTickets = new JLabel("Adult Tickets");
    adTicketsTxt = new JTextField(3);
    adTicketsTxt.setEditable(false);

    chTickets = new JLabel("Child Tickets");
    chTicketsTxt = new JTextField(3);
    chTicketsTxt.setEditable(false);

    popCorn = new JLabel("Popcorn");
    popcornTxt = new JTextField(3);
    popcornTxt.setEditable(false);

    drinkS = new JLabel("Drinks");
    drinksTxt = new JTextField(3);
    drinksTxt.setEditable(false);

    //Create a border title
    sales.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Sales"));
    sales.add(adTickets);
    sales.add(adTicketsTxt);
    sales.add(chTickets);
    sales.add(chTicketsTxt);
    sales.add(popCorn);
    sales.add(popcornTxt);
    sales.add(drinkS);
    sales.add(drinksTxt);

    eastPanel.add(sales);
    add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

//Writing a private bottom method 
private void bottomPanel(){
    southPanel = new JPanel();

    totSales = new JLabel("Total Sales:");

    TotalSalesTxt = new JTextField(10);
    TotalSalesTxt.setEditable(false);

    calcSalesButton = new JButton("Calculate Sales Total");
    calcSalesButton.addActionListener(new CalcSalesButtonListener());

    closeButton = new JButton("Close");
    closeButton.addActionListener(new CloseButtonListener()); 

    southPanel.add(totSales);
    southPanel.add(TotalSalesTxt);
    southPanel.add(calcSalesButton);
    southPanel.add(closeButton);

    add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

//Action Events will handle the calculate button and quantity input
private class CalcSalesButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        TS = new TheaterSales_1();

           adTicketsTxt.setText(String.format("$%,.2f",   
                   TS.getAdultTicketSales()));

                   chTicketsTxt.setText(String.format("$%,.2f",  

                   TS.getChildTicketSales()));
        popcornTxt.setText(String.format("$%,.2f", TS.getPopcornSales()));
        drinksTxt.setText(String.format("$%,.2f", TS.getDrinkSales()));
        TotalSalesTxt.setText(String.format("$%,.2f", TS.getTotalSales())); 
        }
    }

 private class CloseButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == closeButton){
            System.exit(0);
        }   
}
}
//Run the GUI program
public static void main(String[] args){
    new G_Driver();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger IDE and stepped through the code to see where the anomalous values come from?  This is what you should do before posting here.  When you've done that, if you still can't find the problem, then ask a _specific_ question (more specific than "please debug my code").

Comment: Please, reduce your posted code in order to make it more readable

Comment: I looked into my actionListener method and it looks like the output should come out for ex. 20 adult tickets times the price: 9.50 the sales for adult tickets would display $190.

Comment: Yes i have debugged it, otherwise i would have asked why isn't my build clean. Our professor taught us to debug and see if the code is clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listener of the button does

```
TS = new TheaterSales_1();
```

and then gets the values from this new TheaterSales_1 instance. And the constructor of TheaterSales_1 does

```
public TheaterSales_1(){    
    adultTickets = 0;
    childTickets = 0;
    popcorn = 0;
    drinks = 0; 
}
```

So it's quite expected that everything comes out as 0.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, i understand what i need to fix and do now.